# Save for loop result as string

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
    String input[] = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");

        for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            if (i==input.length-1) {
                System.out.print(input[i]+" ");
            } else {
                    System.out.print(input[i]+", ");
            }
        }
```

The result is that i print to console something like "CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Phone".
I want to save the result of the for loop as a string variable instead, so then i can do

```
     String query = "select "+result above+" from table";
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to concatenate strings together. (it is technically possible to use String objects, and concatenate them together using the + operator, but that has a lot of downsides...)

```
    String input[] = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // create empty StringBuilder instance
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        sb.append(input[i]);     //append element
        if (i==input.length-1) {
            sb.append(" ");      //append space
        } else {
            sb.append(", ");     //append comma
        }
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    Systemout.println(result);
```

Or you could build ([see Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)) the whole query using a StringBuilder object, with methods for each part ( `addFields(StringBuilder sb)`, `addFromPart(StringBuilder sb)`, `addWhereClause(StringBuilder sb)`), and voila, you have the insides of a small data access framework...

```
public abstract class MyQueryBuilder {

    protected abstract void addFields(StringBuilder sb);
    protected abstract void addFromPart(StringBuilder sb);
    protected abstract void addWhereClause(StringBuilder sb);

    public final String getQuery() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT ");

        addFields(sb); //this adds the fields to be selected
        sb.append(" FROM ");

        addFromPart(sb); //this adds the tables in the FROM clause

        addWhereClause(sb); //this adds the where clause
        //...etc
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good, it works. I use the query string and finally i do: request.getRequestDispatcher("/response.jsp").forward(request, response); On this jsp i want now to export the shown table as PDF using JasperReports. It does not work to use the result string as a parameter for the query in IReport design.

Answer (score 3):

You keep appending into a `StringBuilder` and then convert it to `String`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
  if (i==input.length-1) {
     System.out.print(input[i]+" ");
     sb = sb.concat(input[i] + ",");
  } else {
     System.out.print(input[i]+", ");
     sb = sb.concat(input[i] + ",");
  }
}
```

Then,

```
String query = "select "+sb.toString()+" from table";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a StringBuilder instead of printing the values out.

```
String input[] = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        if (i==input.length-1) {
            builder.append(input[i]+" ");
        } else {
                builder.append(input[i]+", ");
        }
    }
```

Regards,
kayz